# CredentialHandler encoding in base64 with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to configure a CredentialHandler in Tomcat 8 (8.0.36).
The password in DB are hashed with md5 and encode in base64

I'm trying the following configuration in the context.xml

```
<Realm>
<CredentialHandler
className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
algorithm="md5"
encoding="base64"/>
</realm>
```

When present, the encoding attributes is ignored. and the CredentialHandler only work when the password are hashed without any encoding afterward.

Did I missuse the encoding attribute ?

Thanks,
Arthur